# Modifying User Data with Class and Provider (Without FireBase)

Tags: forms, flutter, dart, flutter-provider, textformfield

I'm currently making UserPage and UserModifyPage. And now I have UserClass that just stores User Information, and User-Provider to modify UserData.

But when I click the `MODIFY` Page, it just shows

> The getter 'id' was called on null.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MaIO.jpg)

So this picture is 'Settings.dart' Page display UserName and UserEmail

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88Qq6.jpg)

And the other one is the ModifyUser.dart page that modifies UserData.

Here are my codes below.

**1. User.dart (Model)**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class User{
  String id;
  String userName;
  String email;
  // final String photoURL;
  // List<String> photoURL;
  String photoURL;
  String userAddress;
  
  User({
    // this.id,
    @required this.id,
    @required this.userName,
    @required this.email,
    @required this.photoURL,
    @required this.userAddress
  });

  factory User.from(User user){
    return User(
      id: user.id ?? '',
      userName: user.userName ?? '',
      email: user.email ?? '',
      // photoURL: user.photoURL ?? [],
      photoURL: user.photoURL ?? '',
      userAddress: user.userAddress ?? '',
    );
  }
}
```

**2. UserProvider.dart**

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/model/game/Users.dart';


class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier{
  List<User> _userInfoList = [];
  User _userModify;

  List<User> get userInfoList {
    return [..._userInfoList];
  }

  User get userModify{
    return User.from(_userModify);
  }
  setname(User user){
    _userModify.userName = user.userName;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void createUserInfo(User userModfiy){
    if (userModify != null){
      // User.fro = userModify.id ?? '';
      final User modifyUser = User.from(userModfiy);
      // modifyUser.id = modifyUser.id ?? 'test';
      // modifyUser.email = modifyUser.email ?? '';
      modifyUser.userName = modifyUser.userName ?? '';

    }
  }

  void changeUserInfo(User userModfiy, String userName, String email, String imageURL, String address){
    // userModfiy.userName = userName
    // userModfiy.email = email;
    // userModfiy.photoURL = imageURL;
    // userModfiy.userAddress = address;
    // notifyListeners();
    final int index = _userInfoList.indexWhere((userInfo) => userInfo.id == _userModify.id);
    if(index != 1){
      final User modifyUser = User.from(userModify);
      modifyUser.userName = userName;
      modifyUser.email = email;
      modifyUser.photoURL = imageURL;
      modifyUser.userAddress = address;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**3. Settings.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/Provider/users.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/app_screens/app_attributes/SettingsImage.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/model/game/Users.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/shared/style.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/widgets/Commons/details_form.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/app_screens/SideMenu.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


class Setting extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SettingState createState() => _SettingState();
}

class _SettingState extends State<Setting> {
  User userModification;
  final TextEditingController userNameTextController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController userEmailTextController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController userAddressController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController userImageTextController = TextEditingController();
  // @override
  // void initState(){
  //   setState((){
  //     userModification = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false).userModify;
  //   });
  //   if(userModification == null){
  //     print("Pass me the Salt Please Man!!!");
  //     // final List<User> userInfoList = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false).i
  //   }
  // }
  AppBar _buildAppBarSettings(){
    return AppBar(
      title: Text("SETTINGS"),
      backgroundColor: appBarColor,
      centerTitle: true,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: SideMenu(),
      appBar: _buildAppBarSettings(),
      body: _buildSettingsBody(context),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSettingsBody(BuildContext context){
    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Container(
      height: screenHeight,
      color: backgroundColor,
      child: Stack(
        overflow: Overflow.visible,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: defaultPadding),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  _buildProfileImage(),
                  SizedBox(height: defaultPadding * 4),
                  _buildProfileInfo(),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ),
          _buildEditButton(context)
        ], 
      )
    );
  }

  Widget _buildProfileImage(){
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(child: ProfileImageButton(),),
        SizedBox(height: defaultPadding),
        Center(
          child: Text(_getUserName(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24)),
        ),
      ]
    );
  }

  Widget _buildProfileInfo(){
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        DetailsForm(
          contentsTitle: "Local ID",
          contentsInfo: "8VxqWO9pRBTvpLGxFXquloo97X13",
          marginBottom: defaultPadding * 2,
        ),
        DetailsForm(
          contentsTitle: "Email",
          contentsInfo: _getEmail(),
          marginBottom: defaultPadding * 2,
        ),
        DetailsForm(
          contentsTitle: "Address",
          contentsInfo: _getAddress(),
          marginBottom: defaultPadding * 2,
        ),
      ]
    );
  }

  Widget _buildEditButton(BuildContext context){
    return Positioned(
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      
      child: FlatButton(
        shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: lineColor)),
        color: Colors.black87,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(defaultPadding / 2),
          child: Text("EDIT", style: settingsMainFont),
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/modify");
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  String _getUserName(){
    return userNameTextController.text == null ||
      userNameTextController.text.trim().isEmpty ? 'YourName'
      : userNameTextController.text;
  }

  String _getEmail(){
    return userEmailTextController.text == null ||
      userEmailTextController.text.trim().isEmpty? 'text@gmail.com'
      : userEmailTextController.text;
  }

  String _getImageLink(){
    return userImageTextController.text == null ||
      userImageTextController.text.trim().isEmpty? 'http://url.com'
      : userImageTextController.text;
  }

  String _getAddress(){
    return userAddressController.text == null ||
      userAddressController.text.trim().isEmpty? 'YourLocation'
      : userAddressController.text;
  }
}
```

**4. ModifyProfile.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/Provider/users.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/app_screens/SideMenu.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/model/game/Users.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/shared/style.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/widgets/Commons/details_form.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/widgets/DetailsPage/label.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'package:flutter_app/model/game/Users.dart';


class ModifyProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ModifyProfileState createState() => _ModifyProfileState();
}

class _ModifyProfileState extends State<ModifyProfile> {
  final _formModifyKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final TextEditingController userNameTextController = TextEditingController();
  
  User user;
  String _userName = 'UserName';
  String _email = 'dddd@gmail.com';
  String _imageURL = 'https://www.naver.com';
  String _address = 'SK Seongsu V1 CENTER I, Seongsu-dong 2-ga, Seongdong-du, Seoul, S.Korea';
  bool _isInit = false;

  final Map<String, dynamic> _formUserData = {
    'username': '',
    'email': '',
    'imageURL': '',
    'Address': '',
    // ''
  };


  Widget _buildModifyAppBar(){
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: appBarColor,
      title: Text("MODIFY PROFILE"),
      centerTitle: true,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildModifyBody(){
    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Container(
      height: screenHeight,
      color: backgroundColor,
      child: Stack(
        overflow: Overflow.visible,
        children: [
          Padding(
            // padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: defaultPadding, horizontal: defaultPadding),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(defaultPadding * 2),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Consumer<UserProvider>(
                builder: (ctx, user, _){
                  final List<User> userList = user.userInfoList;
                  if(user != null && !_isInit){
                    print("Initialize..");
                    _formUserData['username'] = userList;
                    _formUserData['email'] = userList;
                    _formUserData['imageURL'] = userList;
                    _formUserData['Address'] = userList;
                  }
                  return Form(
                    key: _formModifyKey,
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Label(label: "UserName"),
                        // _buildModifyText(),
                        _buildUserNameModify(),
                        // Label(label: "Email"),
                        // _buildModifyText(),
                        // _buildUserEmailModify(),
                        // Label(label: "Image URL"),
                        // _buildModifyText(),
                        // // _buildUserImageURLModify(),
                        // Label(label: "Address"),
                        // _buildModifyText(),
                        // _buildUserAddressModify(),
                      ],
                    )
                  );
                }
              )
              
            )
          ),
          _buildModifyForm(),
        ],
      )
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: _buildModifyAppBar(),
      body: _buildModifyBody(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildUserNameModify(){
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
         TextFormField(
          // controller: SideMenu().userNameTextController,
          validator: (value){
            if(value.isEmpty) {return 'Please enter some text';}
            return null;
          },
          onChanged: (value){
            _formModifyKey.currentState.validate();
          },
          onSaved: (value){
            print("User Edition!!!!!");
            setState((){
              _formUserData['username'] = value;
              // _userName = value;
              print(value);
            });
            print(value);
          },
        ),
        SizedBox(height: defaultPadding * 2),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildModifyForm(){
    return Positioned(
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      
      child: FlatButton(
        shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: lineColor)),
        color: Colors.black87,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(defaultPadding / 2),
          child: Text("MODIFY", style: settingsMainFont),
        ),
        onPressed: () => _submitForm(context)
      ),
    );
  }



  void _submitForm(BuildContext context){
    if(!_formModifyKey.currentState.validate()) return;
    _formModifyKey.currentState.save();
    
    Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).createUserInfo(user);
    print(user.userName);
    // print(user.email);
    // Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).changeUserInfo(user, _userName, _email, _imageURL, _address);
    // print(_userName);
    // print(_email);
    // print(_imageURL);
    // print(_address);
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in your `changeUserInfo`. You are not using the parameter, userModify. To use it, you should change the relevant part with the following:

```
 void changeUserInfo(User userModify, String userName, String email, String imageURL, String address){
    // userModfiy.userName = userName
    // userModfiy.email = email;
    // userModfiy.photoURL = imageURL;
    // userModfiy.userAddress = address;
    // notifyListeners();
    // In here!
    final int index = _userInfoList.indexWhere((ui) => ui.id == userModify.id);
    if(index != 1){
      final User modifyUser = User.from(userModify);
      modifyUser.userName = userName;
      modifyUser.email = email;
      modifyUser.photoURL = imageURL;
      modifyUser.userAddress = address;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
```